# Let f:(0,∞) -> R be a function such that f(1)=0, f is differentiable at 1 and f'(1)=1. Suppose that f(xy)=f(x)+f(y) for all x,y in (0,∞)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, functions, derivatives

prove that lim(h->0) (f(1+h))/h = 1.

prove that f is differentiable on (0,∞) and find a formula for f'.

prove that (f(e^x)-x)'= 0 for all x in R.

I am unsure where to start with all of these problems. I feel I may be missing something obvious as to where to start with the first question but I am totally lost.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 2):

f'(1)= $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(1+h) - f(1)}{h}(f(1)=0)=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(1+h)}{h}=1$

---

Now f'(x)=$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x[1+h]) - f(x)}{xh}$(as h->0 and x is finite implies xh->0)

=$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x) +f(1+h)-f(x)}{xh}$

$=\  \frac{1}{x}\times\ lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(1+h)}{h} =\  \frac{1}{x}$

---

Hence f(x) = ln(x) + c , therefore f($e^x$) - x = c (c'=0)